# Cannot create new record with self Joins relationship User Table in Rails and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I got a problem with my rails app. Here is my code in my Model:

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many   :assistants,  class_name: User, foreign_key: :manager_id
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: User

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  #validation       
  validates :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :birth_date, presence: true


end
```

Here is my Migration:

```
    class AddReferenceToUserTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :manager_id, :integer
  end
end
```

BUT here is the error in my VIEW:

Sign up
1 error prohibited this user from being saved:
**Manager must exist**

May I know what wrong with my code?

Thanks,
Randz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a rails 5 application belongs to is by default required. If a user will not always have a manager then you want

```
belongs_to :manager, class_name: User, required: false
```

Comment: Thanks! Its working now.. Is required a new feature? or I am the only one who doesnt know about it? LOL Thanks!